# does object sink in water in absence of third medium like air?

Tags: pressure, density

I challenged my friend about the following:

I told him if we filled a bottle with water and we put a stone inside of it with condition no existence of air bobbles in the bottle, I told him the stone and water will become one model and the stone will not sink if you flip the bottle, while my friend says that the stone will flip due to the gravity.

My concern is by making the bottle without air inside, so the stone and the water will have enough pressure to make this bottle + water + stone as one object and all as one modal.

**Thinking aloud**

in a non gravitational force (external on the bottle), the only working forces are the particles towards each others ( same as the stone it self and its molecules) + (water and its molecules), the water will apply force towards the stone and also the stone towards the water. ( there will be a binding energy between the water and the stone).

so, based on the universal gravitation equation the force of gravity will be very high since there is no distance between water and stone and both will form one system.

if we flip the bottle, as if the bottle is rotating around an axis, the facts about this rotating object are

1. There is no centripetal force since the space is a non gravitational
2. There is kinetic energy due to the rotation of the body
3. There is no moment of inertia , angular momentum, Torque, since the distance between the axis and the object is zero.

Based on mentioned above, what will make the stone to sink?

Hope my question is clear

Comment: The buoyancy does not depend on any external static pressure, it is an effect only dependent on gravitation (or another force, such as centrifugal forces in a rotating frame of reference) and the different densities of the objects in question.

Comment: @SebastianRiese if i put this modal in a pure vacuum where there is no gravitational forces only the bottle rotating on a fixed axis, does my concept works? the modal will work and the stone stay still?

Comment: i would like to know why the -1 i got it?

Comment: The water and the stone do not form a combined material. The stone stays separate. Whether it's gravity or some other force causing a net acceleration on the bottle, the stone will always shift to the side of the bottle in the opposite direction of the net acceleration (or the same direction of the gravitational force) because it is denser and has low buoyancy. Air bubbles are not in any way the reason that stones sink.

Comment: @Jim , can you write it as answer to mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The water and the stone do not form a combined material. The stone stays separate. Whether it's gravity or some other force causing a net acceleration on the bottle, the stone will always shift to the side of the bottle in the opposite direction of the net acceleration (or the same direction of the gravitational force) because it is denser and has low buoyancy. Air bubbles are not in any way the reason that stones sink.

Answer (score 3):

When you flip the system (bottle, stone and water) the potential energy of the system, with the stone at the top, will be such that there is a lower potential energy situation with the stone at the bottom.
So the stone will fall with the water flowing past the stone thus lowering the potential energy of the system.

Comment: it cannot reach a stage that the stone and the water are same system? for example if i flip the stone, the materials inside are flipped without moving, which means the material on the surface of the stone will stay there and same those in the bottom, what is the difference in this system when I try to build it with different materials?

Comment: I edited my question, hope its more clear now, and thank you for the help